# Show that $4x_1^2+8x_2x_1+30x_2^2>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Show that $4x_1^2+8x_2x_1+30x_2^2>0$

Where $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$

I don't really know how to show that it holds, but to to my intuition this is very true, but I just don't know how to show it exactly.

Comment: Can you find the minimum of this function and show that it is > 0?

Comment: What if $x_1=x_2=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $4x_{1}^2+8x_{1}x_{2}+30x_{2}^{2}=4(x_{1}+x_{2})^{2}+26x_{2}^{2}\ge 0$

Comment: Good but more of an answer than a hint